# HTML and CSS, can't get the text to float next to an image correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my text to the right of an image but i've tried to float it right, i tried to even put it in a flexbox but nothing is seeming to work out very well. Here is the code that I have..

```
    <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">Kur Gin</h2>
                          <p>
                         <img class="img-responsive" style="height: 40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/KurGin.jpg" alt="" />
                        </p>
                            <p>
                            Our gin, Kur (pronounced "cure") is made in the London Dry Gin style and is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat that emphasizes a backbone of classic juniper aromas and flavors with subtle citrus (Seville orange) as well as Douglas Fir and Braeburn apples from Mr. Liedholm's back yard.

                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">Stark Vatten</h2>
                        <p>
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/StarkVatten.jpg" alt="" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                         Our vodka, Stark Vatten (Swedish for “strong water”), is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat and pure, filtered water to create a clean, viscous, oily vodka that displays a definitive classic European style while remaining a distinctive local product.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">White Dog Bourbon</h2>
                        <p>
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/bourbon.jpg" alt=""  />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: all of the text in the p tag under the image i need to somehow put it to the right and keep it in the tab panel, some stuff that I have tried took it out of the tabs panel completely and I had to redo it a few times already...thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just simply wrap a table around it? Put the image in the first column and the text in the second. Give it no borders so the table remains invisible. I mean, all that CSS positioning will eventually work, but getting that perfectly in all browsers can be a huge pain..

Comment: @icecub a table would not be semantic. This isn't tabular data. No reason to recommend the improper use of an element when there are other solutions that will work and aren't semantically incorrect.

Comment: OP do you have any additional CSS or just bootstrap? And is this bootstrap 3 or 4? Please update your post's tag list with whatever version of bootstrap you're using.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I know but check the amount of divs in there. Seems to me most of his script isn't semantic to begin with. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @icecub just because they have other non-semantic code (or could use more semantic code) doesn't mean you should continue to use or suggest improper HTML.  Like I said, there are probably a half-dozen ways to address this, all of which can be achieved with semantic markup.

Comment: @Jason the below answer(s) should cover your problem, but save yourself a headache and don't use inline styles (outside javascript dom manipulations). Separate all your css into a stylesheet and this will be much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wrapper for image and `p`text, make that wrapper a flex container having `align-items: center;` (if you want it vertically centered to the image)  and give the the `p` the settings below.

```css
.wrap {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.wrap p {
flex:  1 0 100px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_default_1">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">Kur Gin</h2>
                        <div class="wrap">
                         <img class="img-responsive" style="height: 40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="http://placehold.it/200x600/fa0" alt="" />
                            <p>Our gin, Kur (pronounced "cure") is made in the London Dry Gin style and is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat that emphasizes a backbone of classic juniper aromas and flavors with subtle citrus (Seville orange) as well as Douglas Fir and Braeburn apples from Mr. Liedholm's back yard.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_2">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">Stark Vatten</h2>
                        <div class="wrap">
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="http://placehold.it/200x600/fa0" alt="" />
                        <p>                        
                         Our vodka, Stark Vatten (Swedish for “strong water”), is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat and pure, filtered water to create a clean, viscous, oily vodka that displays a definitive classic European style while remaining a distinctive local product.</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_default_3">
                        <h2 class="text-dark-green">White Dog Bourbon</h2>
                        <div class="wrap">
                        <p>
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="http://placehold.it/200x600/fa0" alt=""  />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.pull-left` class on the `p` that wraps your images, and `.clearfix` on the parent to clear the float. Then you'll want to apply margin and padding to the text so that it aligns with your image.

Ignore the `.tab-pane` css here - just used for the demo so your hidden panes would show.

```css
/* ignore this - just for demo */
.tab-pane {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active clearfix" id="tab_default_1">
    <h2 class="text-dark-green">Kur Gin</h2>
    <p class="pull-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="height: 40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/KurGin.jpg" alt="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Our gin, Kur (pronounced "cure") is made in the London Dry Gin style and is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat that emphasizes a backbone of classic juniper aromas and flavors with subtle citrus (Seville orange) as well as Douglas
      Fir and Braeburn apples from Mr. Liedholm's back yard.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane clearfix" id="tab_default_2">
    <h2 class="text-dark-green">Stark Vatten</h2>
    <p class="pull-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/StarkVatten.jpg" alt="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Our vodka, Stark Vatten (Swedish for “strong water”), is produced with Washington heirloom variety red winter wheat and pure, filtered water to create a clean, viscous, oily vodka that displays a definitive classic European style while remaining a distinctive
      local product.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane clearfix" id="tab_default_3">
    <h2 class="text-dark-green">White Dog Bourbon</h2>
    <p class="pull-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="height:40em; width:30em; margin-top:25px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;" src="app/what-we-make/images/bourbon.jpg" alt="" />
    </p>
    <p>
      Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit
      esse molestie consequat
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text to the right of the image without the use of a table by using

"float:left" in the inline style of the image.